# How do i use a Fabrik (joomla component) form to connect to database table & search for match & return a result?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

I am using the [Joomla!](http://www.joomla.org/) component [Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/).

The functionality I am trying to get is to have users buy a unique code from my website using e-junkie. On completion of payment, e-junkie will process a script that will send the code to a MySQL database table.

After buying, they will then be redirected to a page on the website to activate their code by filling in a form. In order to activate their code, they will need to enter data into three text fields:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Unique Code

The form is already set up with Fabrik and displayed nicely on the website.

What I need now is when the form is submitted, I need it to connect to the database where the unique codes are stored, search the database table for the matching `firstname`,`lastname` and `unique code` and return a success message if a match is found and a failure message if no match is found.

Fabrik allows for PHP plugin scripts to run when the form is submitted, I will use a separate plugin for each field on the form.

So far I have come up with the snippet of code below which would be executed when the form is submitted. I am just attempting to validate the `firstname` field on the form at this stage just to get it working. once it is working i will duplicate the code and adapt it for the other fields (e.g `lastname` and `uniquecode`).

Problem is i just cant get it to work. It uses Joomla's JFactory/getDBO to connect to the database.

My Table name is `travelcodes`
The fields on the form are, `firstname`, `lastname` and `uniquecode` 
the columns on the table are also `firstname`,`lastname` and `uniquecode`

```
$firstname = '{travelcodes___firstname}';
$value = '{tablename___firstname}';
$db =JFactory::getDBO();
$query=("SELECT firstname FROM travelcodes where field = '$firstname'");
$db->setQuery($query);
$response = $db->loadResult();
if ($response == $firstname) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Bailey

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem using the following setting

I think you will need to add JRequest::getVar before ('you_element') and have the setting to be onBeforeProcess

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());  
$value = JRequest::getVar('off_line_ap___offline_reason');
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$uid = $user->id;
$db->setQuery("INSERT INTO d2_exchange_log (date_time, part, quantity, user_id, purpose) VALUES ('{$date}', '{$value}', '99','{$uid}', 'Test')");

$submissionsNo=$db->loadResult();
```